# Get generic type class during runtime

Tags: java

I've been trying to figure out how to determinate the classname of a generic type at runtime, but maybe I need to rephrase my thinking regarding this.

For example I have:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new PersistentHashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Will I be able to retrieve the classnames `java.lang.String` and `java.lang.Integer` from the `PersistentHashMap` for example?

Comment: Why would you want to know the names of the classes?

Comment: Need that since I'm doing a persistent Map, it needs to get and store the class name

Comment: Again, why would you need it?

Comment: Huh? I need to store the class name to a persistent storage

Comment: usually the workaround is to have the constructor for your class recieve and store two Class instances explicitely

Comment: @radai Can you site some example?

Comment: I don't understand how will you use the class types. Knowing this, the problem might be of your design and not of code. By the way, at runtime every `Map<SomeClass, AnotherClass>` will be turned into a plain `Map`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I understand your part, however, I can actually store objects without dealing with the K,V generic type, however I just want to know how to do this and perhaps use it in my PersistentHashMap

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza For example use it to further improve query, etc.

Comment: I can't see any query improvisation here (at least that you provide a **real world** example). As stated in SLaks' answer, you can't. As stated by @radai, the only way you can *know* the types is passing them in your class constructor or somewhere else. Also, I can't find `PersistentHashMap` as a Java standard type.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza PeristentHashMap is just an example, something similar to the one I have in GitHub. Yah, type erasures, and Generic types are just for compile time correctness...

Comment: @xybrek - guice has type literals for these things - https://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html - but its probbaly overkill for you. just change your constructor to be PersistentHashMap<String,Integer>(String.class, Integer.class) for example, and then you have 2 Class instances that you can store and use with reflection (better store just the class names as Strings)

Comment: The doubt still remains: what is the real purpose for this? Just plain *curiosity*?

Comment: @radai I guess this is the only way, but as much as I want to make my "API" simple, I will just rely on the getting of the classname during the Map put/get methods... thanks anyway.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza hmmm... let see, well, when I do Map<String,SomeClass>, I want to effectively put the class name as property of the Entity (see GAE Entity) like e.put("map.key", "thekey"); e.put("map.key.type", "java.lang.String"); e.put("map.value", serialize(someobject));  e.put("map.value.type", "com.mycompany.SomeClass"); // Something like this...

Comment: And the **real world** usage for this is...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I mean I'm storing Map entries as GAE Datastore entities :-)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What real word use are you trying to ask? I'm using my library for my web project

Comment: Looks more like a design problem then. What is your real problem (since this is the solution you tried to use but didn't work)?

Comment: Also, by **real world** I mean that the code is in a real working application and other people could read the question and use it in its own application (for example, me).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza hmmm, my mapping library works pretty well, and I will be able to do java.util.Map query, i.e Iterator for billions of records (without performance and memory) issue because I just mapped the interface to the existing query interface provided by the GAE Datastore...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your problem.The only thing I can say is that you can't do what you're trying. Also, I can't provide any further help.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza and that I don't have to deal with GAE Datastore Entities and stuff like that, simple POJO's would do for us to store to the GAE Datastore, hence: Map m = Datastorecast.getMap("messages"); m.put("luiggi", "hello world!"); // And from what I see, Project Voldemort works just like a big map or something

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No problem. I understand that generic types are compile time only. The best answer would be from radai I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure), this is not possible.